# Does blunt end have a hydrogen bond?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, molecular-genetics, biotechnology

I am an undergraduate student of biology.

I saw a lecturer online, who said that sticky ends makes [phosphodiester and hydrogen bonds](https://www.answers.com/chemistry/What_is_the_difference_between_phosphodiester_bonds_and_hydrogen_bonds) cut. (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphodiester_bond)).

But why blunt end just makes phospodiester bonds cut?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! Do you know how the structure of DNA looks like, and where phosphodiester and hydrogen bonds are located? Did your lecturer show you an [image](https://ib.bioninja.com.au/_Media/restriction-enzymes_med.jpeg) of sticky-ends and blunt-ends cuts?

Comment: Does this help? @ https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21129/

Comment: @BrendanDarrer thank you for sharing with me, but unfortunately the book didn't contains the answer that i'm looking for.

Comment: @Domen hi, thank you for your warm welcome. Yes i know the structure of DNA looks like and where are the bonds located. My lecturer shows me how the sticky-ends and blunt-ends looks like using GAATTC strand (for sticky-ends) and CCCGGG strand (for blunt-ends). Can you please enlight me about this cause i really need to know. Thank you so much

Comment: Have you found the answer or are you still looking for one?

In short - Hydrogen bonds occur between the 2 strands, whereas phosphodiester is within the each strand. so a sticky end has a few overhang nucleotides on one strand that are absent in the other strand, hence the hydrogen bond is missing..

Comment: Hi! i'm still looking for the answer. But thanks to you, your answer kinda enlight me. Thank you.